# Content missing for the community promotion advertisement

Tags: bug, design

Language Learning Q&A Area51 proposal site - community promotion advertisement's content is not visible in the Ell site's side bar. For better understanding I clicked the **stats** link there is no content for that proposal site.

I didn't installed any ad-block extensions. Since Wiktionary content is visible for the Wiktionary stats.

The same I recorded:

[image: Issue in Ad section]

Comment: The site recently went into private beta, so it may not be accessible until it goes into open beta. We should probably remove it.